# "Relative" Vaccine Efficacy

Tags: sample, definition

Merck just released data on their covid-$19$ antiviral medication.

In the medicated group there were $28$ unfavorable outcomes in $385$ cases. Or ~$7$%

In the placebo group, $53$ negative outcomes in $377$ cases. Or ~$14$%.

Thus it was claimed, correctly according to the definition of vaccine efficacy, the drug appears to be $50$% effective.

My question is:

Should there not be some consideration of magnitude in assessing efficacy.

After all, if the outcomes were $2$% and $4$% or alternatively $45$% and $90$%, all these outcomes would be considered $50$% effective.

But I personally would not consider them equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that this product is a treatment for those who have developed the disease, not a vaccine to prevent it.

Comment: @EdM Yes, as you point out, I'm aware of that and also that they cancelled it for hospitalized patients who were badly off to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should there not be some consideration of magnitude in assessing efficacy.
>
> After all, if the outcomes were 2% and 4% or alternatively 45
> % and 90%, all these outcomes would be considered 50
> % effective.
>
> But I personally would not consider them equivalent.

If you define "effectiveness" as the ratio of probabilities of bad outcomes between drug and control groups, then the "effectiveness" is 50% by definition in the scenarios you cite. Your sense about the importance of the actual magnitudes of the probabilities is wise in several respects. I suspect that your main concern has to do with how *precise* you might expect the estimate of "50% effectiveness" to be.

The *precision* of the estimates of the probabilities mainly depends on the actual numbers of bad outcomes in each group, particularly when probabilities are relatively low. In the data you report, the numbers of events--28 bad events (7.3%) in the drug group and 53 (14.1%) in a similarly sized control group--make it highly likely that there is a real difference between drug and control. If there were no real effect of the drug you would only observe this large a difference in about 0.3% of data samples of this size.

If the situation involved a 2% versus a 4% poor-outcome rate with the same size study, you might have 8 poor outcomes in the drug group and 15 in the control group. By your definition there would still be an observed effectiveness of about 51%, but you couldn't reliably say that the drug had an effect. With so few poor-outcome cases, you might observe that large an apparent effect in about 13% of samples from a population in which the drug actually had no effect. If the probabilities were 2% and 4%, to a first approximation you would need nearly 4 times as large a study to get results as reliable as what you report in terms of an effect/no-effect distinction.

An important question is what *range* of "effectiveness" values might be compatible with these data. For that one might consider the *odds ratio* of poor outcomes between control and drug groups, where the odds within each group is the ratio of poor to good outcomes. A quick calculation suggests that the observed odds ratio of 2.09 in this case could be compatible with a true value as low as 1.08, but also with one as high as 3.10, under the usual criterion of 95% confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Sent me to wikipedia to check out odds ratios. I can see your 2.09. If I read the entry correctly, it seems that an OR equal to 1 implies no causality. So the lower bound of the CI would tend to corroborate my skepticism? But maybe I'm all wet. Kind regards,

Comment: @user663837 skepticism about the effect magnitude is perhaps warranted. Remember, however, it could as easily be greater than observed here, not just lower. Skepticism about _any_ non-zero effect of the drug _within the defined study population_ isn't so warranted. If the drug had no effect, you would see this large a difference in only about 3 out of every 1000 data samples of this size. The usual (arbitrary) standard for "statistical significance" is if fewer than 50 out of every 1000 data samples show so large an observed effect if there isn't one. This study does much better than that.